# An example of a dense and co-dense set in a metric space with countable derived set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A\subset{X}$ such that $A$ and $A^c$ are both dense in $X$. Show that it is not necessary that $A^\prime$ be uncountable. And prove $(A^\prime)^\prime=A^\prime$.

(By $A^\prime$ we mean the set of all limit points of $A$, that is, the [derived set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_%28mathematics%29) of $A$.)

I consider the indiscrete topology that is not single point. In this topology every subset of $X$ with complement both  are dense in $X$ and it is not necessary that $X$ be uncountable. But this topology is not metrizable. Is it true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be $\Bbb Q$, the rationals, with the usual metric, and let $A$ be the set of [dyadic rationals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational), rationals that can be written as fractions whose denominators are powers of $2$. Then $A$ and $X\setminus A$ are both dense in $X$, and $X$ itself is only countable.

HINT for the proof that $(A')'=A'$: If $A$ is dense, then $\operatorname{cl}A=X$, and that if $A$ and $X\setminus A$ are both dense, then $X$ has no isolated points.

Comment: why $X$ has no isolated point?,it is contradiction?

Comment: @amir: Show that if $x$ is an isolated point, and $D$ is any dense subset of $X$, then $x\in D$. In the present setting $x$ would therefore have to belong to $A$ and to $X\setminus A$.

Comment: yes I understand ,very thanks.

Comment: @Amir: You’re very welcome.